# How to copy JSON array columns from Azure Cosmos DB enabled Mongo DB document to Snowflake column (String/Variant) using Azure Data Factory V2?

Tags: azure, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, azure-data-factory, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I am trying to copy Azure Cosmos-DB enabled Mongo-DB collection Documents to the Snowflake table using Azure Data Factory V2. Some of the columns present in the Document are array (multiple values). I thought that: If I use String or Variant column at the destination "Snowflake", Azure Data Factory V2 will be able to copy it successfully but it is failing with error: (**ErrorCode=JsonUnsupportedHierarchicalComplexValue,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=The retrieved type of data JArray is not supported yet. Please either remove the targeted column 'REQUESTDATE' or enable skip incompatible row to skip the issue rows.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common,'**):

Mapping:

[image]

Error:

[image]

I have tried everything but was unsuccessful. I also noticed that even Data Flow does not support Mongo DB as a source. Any assistance will be appreciated.

Thanks,
Bilal

Comment: check the `Map complex values to string` feature of mapping and run the trigger the debug to run the pipeline.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the response. As you can already see in the attached image that "Map complex values to string" is already checked :). @PratikLad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the same and also failed for the same `JArray` data type may be it is taking it as Array directly To overcome this issue You can use this following workaround:

- **First you need to take on copy activity to copy data from Cosmos with mongo db to CSV file** and, in the source add the Cosmos with mongo db and select your container.[image]
- In sink add Blob storage with CSV file so it will copy data there.
  [image]
- Import mapping and check the**Map complex values to string**
  [image]
- **Then take another Copy activity to copy data from CSV file to snowflake** and, in the source add the Same CSV file where you copied data in earlier Copy activity.
  [image]
- In sink add Snowflake dataset as destination.
  [image]
- Add mapping according to your requirement.
  [image]
- Run the pipeline It will copy the data in snowflake.

Comment: Yup, I used this workaround. But yes, it works so its the correct answer. Thanks